# Ruby trying to use %x to print command line output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

this is what i have for my small ruby program. It may seem trivial but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

location = "/home/"

puts %x ("ls " + location)
```

I get an error saying this syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting $end
puts %x ("ls " + location).

Can someone offer me an explanation to what i'm doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the brackets immediately adjacent to the `%x` or it's not syntactically valid:

```
%x( ... )  # Valid, enclosed with brackets.
%x ( ... ) # Invalid, %x alone makes no sense.
```

Like `%q` and others, `%x` can use `[ ]`, `{ }` and `< >` as brackets.

Comment: What I thought was interesting is that `x = ['a','b','c']; x [1] => 'a'` works. Perhaps this an error with the parser.

Comment: Is there a reason why it might not let me use ls outside the current working directory? Anytime I use %x("ls somelocation/")

I'm left sh: 1: ls : not found

Comment: user1787282, I believe I am able to do this outside of the current working directory.

Comment: Ruby is somewhat slack in what it will allow for *method calls* like `f (x)` or `f [x]` but `%x[` is a token. If `ls` is not working, it's probable that your `ENV['PATH']` has been nulled out or broken.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
location = "/home/"

puts %x(ls #{location})
```

Note the space between the %x and the location and you don't need the quotes.

Comment: Is there a reason why it might not let me use ls outside the current working directory? Anytime I use %x("ls somelocation/") I'm left sh: 1: ls : not found

Comment: ls somelocation/ will always be relative to the current directory, it's equivalent to ls ./somelocation/.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding whitespace between `%x` and `(`. The following will work:

```
location = "/home/"

puts %x[ls #{location}]
puts %x(ls #{location})
puts `ls #{location}`
puts exec "ls #{location}"
```